# Pattern to match the label of a JavaScript object field when the colon is not followed by another colon or an equal sign

Tags: syntax-highlighting, regular-expression

I wrote a syntax highlighting .vim file. One of the expressions is used to color the label in a JavaScript object declaration:

```
name: 'value'
^^^^
```

I want to see the `name` in a different color.

My expression looks like this:

```
syn match label "\<[a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z_$0-9]*[ \t]*:[^=:]\="
```

The idea is to avoid seeing `name` as a `label` if the colon is immediately followed by an equal (`=`) or a colon (`:`) as in these two lines, the highlight should not happen:

```
name:=assignment
name::space
```

However, my current expression fails in this situation:

```
name:'value'
     ^
     |
     +---  no space here
```

The effect is that the string (`'value'`) doesn't get highlighted as expected since the first quote (`'`) is viewed as being part of the `label` expression.

How do I test that an expression is not followed by another without *eating* that expression?

Comment: not sure if relevant, but made me think about this https://github.com/romainl/ctags-patterns-for-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

```
syn match label "\<[a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z_$0-9]*\s*:[:=]\@!"
```

First off, general comments.

- `[ \t]` could be `\s`, which match the exact same things.
- `[:=]\@!` is called a *negative lookahead*. So if you have `<atom>\@!` then it only matches if `<atom>` does not match at that position, but it also doesn't "eat" that atom. So it's like saying "all that stuff, *not* followed by a colon or an equals."
- This could also be a bit shorter by taking advantage of character classes:

  ```
  syn match label "\v(\h|\$)(\w|\$)*\s*:[:=]@!"
  ```

  `\h` is the same as `[a-zA-Z_]`, and `\w` is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. And [using `\v` at the beginning](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Simplifying_regular_expressions_using_magic_and_no-magic) allows us to make a bit shorter by removing some backslashes.

Comment: Ah! That works, I tried with `\@!` but left `\=` behind it... without the `\=` it works as expected. Great!